# Stacked histogram will not stack

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn

I am trying to run the following code :

```
variable_values = #numpy vector, one dimension, 5053 values between 1 and 0.
label_values = #numpy vector, one dimension, 5053 values, discrete value of either 1 OR 0.
x = variable_values[variable_values != '?'].astype(float)
y = label_values[variable_values != '?'].astype(float)

print np.max(x) #prints 0.90101
print np.max(y) #prints 1.0


N = 5053
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.45       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 5, stacked=True, normed = True)

#Stack the data
plt.figure()
plt.hist(x, bins, stacked=True, normed = True)
plt.hist(y, bins, stacked=True, normed = True)
plt.show()
```

What I want to achieve is the following graph :

[image]

With the colour on each bar split according to whether its value for `label` is 1 or 0.

Unfortunately my output currently is :

[image: Output]

There are two things incorrect with this - it isn't stacked appropriately first of all. Second of all, the values on the Y axis go up to 1.6, but I believe the Y axis should hold the number of pieces of data that fall into each subgroup (so if all pieces of data had a value of 0-0.25 the only bar that would show data would be the first).

Comment: it's a histogram.. The highest peak will be the most frequent value, not the largest value.

Comment: @M4rtini Sorry, yes you are right about this - why is it printing out a max of 1.6 here then? Ideally what Id like is to have the 5053 pieces of data split into four bars (with the number of pieces of data displayed on the Y axis) and the bars split up by number where label==1 and label==0. Apologies, I got confused by my own question. Will update now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> variable_values = #numpy vector, one dimension, 5053 values between 1 and 0.
>
> label_values = #numpy vector, one dimension, 5053 values, discrete
>   value of either 1 OR 0.

You're trying to use the same bins for x and y. x probably being from 0-1 not including the edges. So y falls outside the range of bins you're plotting.

It's 1.6 because you have chosen to normalize the plot. Set that parameter to false to get the real counts.

This should fix most of these problems:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(5053)
y = np.random.random_integers(0,1, 5053)

# x = variable_values[variable_values != '?'].astype(float)
# y = label_values[variable_values != '?'].astype(float)

print np.max(x) #prints 0.90101
print np.max(y) #prints 1.0


N = 5053
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.45       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 5, stacked=True, normed = True)

bins[0] = 0
bins[-1] = 1

#Stack the data
plt.figure()
plt.hist(y, bins, stacked=True, normed = False)
plt.hist(x, bins, stacked=True, normed = False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a more simple solution:

```
variable_values=np.random.random(size=5053)
label_values=np.random.randint(0,2, size=5053)
plt.hist(variable_values, label='1')
plt.hist(variable_values[label_values==0], label='0')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

[image]

Actually since the `label_values` is either 1 or 0, you don't even need to stack the histgram. Just make a histogram of both 1 and 0's and then superimpose a histogram for the 0's on top.

To use stack histogram, although I prefer only to use when there are many different classes:

```
plt.hist([variable_values[label_values==1],variable_values[label_values==0]], stacked=True, label=['1', '0'])
```